# Send file via Curl in PHP failing with wsl path

Tags: php, curl

Here is my curl code from Postman

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
  CURLOPT_URL => '<url>/upload',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('file'=> new CURLFILE('///wsl.localhost/Ubuntu/home/<path>/file.imscc'),5,2),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: <token>'
  ),
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

which is working fine from postman. Now, If I write same code in PHP, it is not sending.

curl_file_create or new CURLFILE is giving me below path

```
CURLFile Object
(
    [name] => /var/www/<path>/file.imscc
    [mime] => 
    [postname] => 
)
```

Is there anything wrong in the path? I am using ubuntu app in windows and that's why it has wsl in path.

Comment: Please show the original setup / code of your Postman. You're only showing the PHP code that failed. Also, are you running the PHP within the WSL or outside?